# Is "Find out how we can partner your company" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I need to send out a business emailer which ends with the above phrase. Which version is grammatically correct: "Find out how we can partner your business" OR "Find out how we can partner with your business"?

Answer (score 1):

Use "Find out how we can partner with your business"?  It is clearer.

"partner your business" feels incomplete.  It could mean partnering it with something else.

---

For example:

> We partnered A with B.

A and B are joined.

> We partnered with B.

'We' and B are joined.